# How to use nested Joi schemas based on various conditionals

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, joi

I've been researching this particular issue for about a week now but can't seem to find any solid documentation on the most recent version of JOI (17.3.0).

The logic that I am trying to implement is as follows:

if A is populated then B OR C are required.

if F is populated then A AND K are required. (F is required if A is empty)

I've been looking through Joi documentation and have tried various combinations of the functions that are provided. Here is my current code that I'm running which isn't giving me what I want in terms of the logic described.

```
const B = Joi.alternatives().conditional(Joi.ref('#B'), {is: Joi.boolean().valid(false), then : C.required(), otherwise: Joi.date().iso()}).allow("")


 const check = Joi.object().keys({
 
  //Name search
  A: A,
  B: B.when('A', {is: A.required(), then: B.required()}),
  C: C,

  F: F.when('A', {is: '', then: F.required()}),
  K: K.when('F', {is: F.required(), then: K.required()}),
  A: A.when('F', {is: F.required(), then: A.required()}),
   
}).unknown(true);
```

I know it's mostly like based on the loose construction of the schema all together so I'm trying see if there's a way for me to create nested schemas that can be switched based on conditionals such as AND and OR statements. I've seen others concatenate the "when" function to build a custom OR (even AND) conditional but not sure if there is a more cleaner way to do so using Joi 17.3.0

The main issue is that I need to guide the schema based on conditionals instead of just throwing the information into the body hoping that it just works. I'm not getting any syntax errors but when sending requests I don't get the correct responses/errors that I need.

Ideally, I'd like to have it so that it can check when A, B or C are given or if F AND K AND A are given and then based on what is given, it can use the correct schema.

In addition to that, all my references have a ".allow("")" so that the schema doesn't throw an error when nothing is assigned to an unneeded reference. I did this prior to knowing about the any.optional() function. Not sure if that may be an issue but just additional info in case.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [@hapi/joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi).

```
joi.alternatives(
    joi.object({
        A: joi.string().required(),
        B: joi.string().required(),
        C: joi.string().allow(''),
    }),
    joi.object({
        A: joi.string().required(),
        B: joi.string().allow(''),
        C: joi.string().required(),
    }),
    joi.object({
        F: joi.string().required(),
        A: joi.string().required(),
        K: joi.string().required(),
    })
)
```

Feel free to add more alternatives.